# Set MIME associations for MS Works

Tags: mime

My website issues documents in .rtf and .doc format. One of my clients only has MS Works installed on his machine. It seems that his machine is attempting to open the documents in Notepad, which is far from ideal.

The client does have MS Works installed, which would presumably make a better fist of displaying these documents. Does anyone know how he might configure MS Works to take over responsibility for opening application/msword and application/rft MIME types?

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

application/vnd.ms-works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I meant is there anything HE can do? It's more of a Windows question than a web development question.

Cheers